# Powershell. Как подключить Framework для создания формы взамен Windows.Forms?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

При создании GUI форм в Powershell использую Windows Forms:
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

Возможно ли подключить сторонний Framework чтобы преобразовать формы?
Интересует этот https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Скомпилировать при помощи msbuild:

```
msbuild /t:build C:\repos\metroframework-modern-ui-master\MetroFramework.sln
```

Подгрузить DLL в PowerShell и использовать:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\repos\metroframework-modern-ui-master\MetroFramework\bin\Debug\MetroFramework.dll")

$form = [MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm]::new()
$form.Theme = [MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle]::Dark
$form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```

Проверял в PowerShell 5.1, более старой версии нет под рукой.